# How to fork and merge a REST API call that takes a list of id's as query param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I have to call a third party GET API which takes a comma seperated list of ids and returns a JSON response.
Like so:

```
def call(sysid)
   # RestClient GET  https://test.com?ids=sysid.join(',')&....
   # parse response and returns
   # rescue - any error handling
end
```

[RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

But sysid is an input and can sometimes have 300+ elements and due to the limitation of GET, my api call errors out (probably because URL length becomes too big)

How can I efficiently send API calls (in small batches) & merge results back. In doing that:
-

- should I use any [Parallelism](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)

  - if one of the batch call fails, may be add retries

    - if it still fail, stop the whole process & return an error from call()

**Is there a good pattern in Ruby for this type of problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of good ruby pattern but we can solve issue by below code

```
def call(sysid)
  fetch_next = true
  response = {status: true, result: []}
  while fetch_next
    param_value_id = sysid[0..n-1]
    while sysid.present?
      begin
        call API with FARADAY/RestClient with its params as param_value_id.join(',')
        if success
          parse response and append in responses result
        else
          fetch_next = false
          response[:status] = false
          response[:result] = []
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        Rails.logger.warn "Exception raised due to #{e}"
        fetch_next = false
        response[:status] = false
        response[:result] = []
      end
    end
    sysid = sysid.drop(n)
    if sysid.empty?
      fetch_next = false
    end
  end
  response
end
```

EXPLANATION

1. setting **fetch_next** to **true** and **response** hash to be returned from call method.
2. till fetch_next is **true**, we'll fetch **n** ids from **sysid**
3. till sysid is there, we'll call **third party api** with **intended** params
4. if response is **success**, we **append** it in **result key** of **response** hash
5. if there is **failure** or an **exception**, we'll set **fetch_next** to **false**, **status** key of **response** to false and **empty** **result** key
6. In the end we drop **n** values from sysid array and will set fetch_next to **false** if sysid is empty.

you can return response object or send particular response if status is false

This is *pseudo code* but i think it might solve your problem.

Thank you.